# How to make a different background for each link from a navbar?

Tags: html, css

How to make a different background for each link from a navbar?

For example, I want one photo to be my background for Home link, then another photo to be my background for About link and another photo to be my background for Contact me link.

Can this be done with CSS only???

Thank you all in advance :)

Comment: Err… you use a different selector for each one

Comment: <ul class="navmenu">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact-me.html">Contact Me</a></li></ul>

Comment: So, basically I have to add class selector to each of my <li> and then add a different background URL for each, right?

Comment: @C.Felipe Please edit your markup into the question (properly formatted). Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I just started to use Stack Overflow so I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @C.Felipe: to edit a question, [click the 'edit' link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16638248/edit) above, make the changes that have been requested, and click 'Save Edits'. Easy! FWIW, comments aren't usually a good place for code unless it is a _really_ small snippet, and if you do use them, put them in backticks, so it uses `a monospaced font`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### For Links

If you actually mean the background on the links themselves, then apply a css class name to each link and style them individually.  For example:

```
<ul>
    <li class="homeLink"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="aboutLink"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li class="contactLink"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

and in your stylsheet

```
.homeLink { background-image:url(/img/home.jpg); }
.aboutLink { background-image:url(/img/about.jpg); }
.contactLink { background-image:url(/img/contact.jpg); }
```

### For Pages

For pages, apply the css class name to the body tag instead of the link.

```
    <body class="homePage">...
```

or 
        ...
or 
        ...

and in your stylsheet

```
.homePage { background-image:url(/img/home.jpg); }
.aboutPage { background-image:url(/img/about.jpg); }
.contactPage { background-image:url(/img/contact.jpg); }
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Many thanks! I am just a begginer so I don't understand some negative replies above. I appreciate your kindness!!!

Comment: Wait, can I add more than one <body> tags in my HTML? And how do I do that?

Comment: No, you don't want to add more than one body tag in your HTML.  Your original question was unclear, so I wanted to give you an example if your question was about a different background _for each page_.